# Choosing the right ReadP parse result

Tags: parsing, haskell, rfc5322

I'm trying to parse a RFC5322 email address. My parser works in the sense that among the results, one of them is correct. However, how do I go about selecting the “correct” result?

Given the string `Foo Bar <foo@bar.com>`, my parser should produce a value of `Address (Just "Foo Bar") "foo@bar.com"`.

Alternatively, given the string `foo@bar.com`, my parser should produce a value of `Address Nothing "foo@bar.com"`.

The value with the name included is preferred.

My parser looks like this:

```
import           Control.Applicative
import           Data.Char
import qualified Data.Text                     as T
import           Text.ParserCombinators.ReadP

onlyEmail :: ReadP Address
onlyEmail = do
  skipSpaces
  email <- many1 $ satisfy isAscii
  skipSpaces
  return $ Address Nothing (T.pack email)

withName :: ReadP Address
withName = do
  skipSpaces
  name <- many1 (satisfy isAscii)
  skipSpaces
  email <- between (char '<') (char '>') (many1 $ satisfy isAscii)
  skipSpaces
  return $ Address (Just $ T.pack name) (T.pack email)

rfc5322 :: ReadP Address
rfc5322 = withName <|> onlyEmail
```

When I run the parser with `readP_to_S rfc5322 "Foo Bar <foo@bar.com>"`, it produces the following results:

```
[ (Address {addressName = Nothing, addressEmail = "F"},"oo Bar <foo@bar.com>")
, (Address {addressName = Nothing, addressEmail = "Fo"},"o Bar <foo@bar.com>")
, (Address {addressName = Nothing, addressEmail = "Foo"},"Bar <foo@bar.com>")
, (Address {addressName = Nothing, addressEmail = "Foo "},"Bar <foo@bar.com>")
, (Address {addressName = Nothing, addressEmail = "Foo B"},"ar <foo@bar.com>")
, (Address {addressName = Nothing, addressEmail = "Foo Ba"},"r <foo@bar.com>")
, (Address {addressName = Nothing, addressEmail = "Foo Bar"},"<foo@bar.com>")
, (Address {addressName = Nothing, addressEmail = "Foo Bar "},"<foo@bar.com>")
, (Address {addressName = Nothing, addressEmail = "Foo Bar <"},"foo@bar.com>")
, (Address {addressName = Nothing, addressEmail = "Foo Bar <f"},"oo@bar.com>")
, (Address {addressName = Nothing, addressEmail = "Foo Bar <fo"},"o@bar.com>")
, (Address {addressName = Nothing, addressEmail = "Foo Bar <foo"},"@bar.com>")
, (Address {addressName = Nothing, addressEmail = "Foo Bar <foo@"},"bar.com>")
, (Address {addressName = Nothing, addressEmail = "Foo Bar <foo@b"},"ar.com>")
, (Address {addressName = Nothing, addressEmail = "Foo Bar <foo@ba"},"r.com>")
, (Address {addressName = Nothing, addressEmail = "Foo Bar <foo@bar"},".com>")
, (Address {addressName = Nothing, addressEmail = "Foo Bar <foo@bar."},"com>")
, (Address {addressName = Nothing, addressEmail = "Foo Bar <foo@bar.c"},"om>")
, (Address {addressName = Nothing, addressEmail = "Foo Bar <foo@bar.co"},"m>")
, (Address {addressName = Nothing, addressEmail = "Foo Bar <foo@bar.com"},">")
, (Address {addressName = Just "Foo Bar", addressEmail = "foo@bar.com"},"")
, (Address {addressName = Just "Foo Bar ", addressEmail = "foo@bar.com"},"")
, (Address {addressName = Nothing, addressEmail = "Foo Bar <foo@bar.com>"},"")
]
```

In this case, the result I actually want appears third-last in the list. How do I express that preference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not to do preference. Your problem is that your partial parsers are accepting the more bigger string set than really need.

For example, my solution:

```
import           Control.Bool
import           Control.Applicative
import           Data.Char
import qualified Data.Text                     as T
import           Data.Text (Text)
import           Text.ParserCombinators.ReadP

email :: ReadP Text
email = do
    l <- part
    a <- char '@'
    d <- part
    return . T.pack $ l ++ a:d
  where
    part = munch1 (isAscii <&&> (/='@') <&&> (/='<') <&&> (/='>'))

name :: ReadP Text
name = T.pack <$> chainr1 part sep
  where
    part = munch1 (isAlpha <||> isDigit <||> (=='\''))
    sep  = (\xs ys -> xs ++ ' ':ys) <$ munch1 (==' ')

onlyEmail :: ReadP Address
onlyEmail = Address Nothing <$> email

withName :: ReadP Address
withName = do
    n <- name
    skipSpaces
    e <- between (char '<') (char '>') email
    return $ Address (Just n) e

address :: ReadP Address
address = skipSpaces *> (withName <|> onlyEmail)

main = print $ readP_to_S address "Foo Bar <foo@bar.com>"
```

Will be printed:

```
[(Address (Just "Foo Bar") "foo@bar.com","")]
```